# input values does not fill correctly in FormArray

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I have trouble with filling the right values into input fields of a FormArray. Here is my html:

```
<div formArrayName="roles" *ngFor="let role of roles.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'roleNameId' + i}}">Role Name {{i+1}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control"
                        attr.id="{{'roleNameId' + i}}"
                        type="text"
                        formControlName="roleName">
            </div>
            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'identifierId' + i}}">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    attr.id="{{'identifierId' + i}}"
                    formControlName="identifier"> identifier
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                 <button type="button" (click)="removeRole(i)" class="btn btn-danger oi oi-trash"></button>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

So this html is being rendered x times depending on the number of roles i have. This works just fine and no errors are shown.

But here is the Problem: When i remove one Role which is not the last of the Array, the input fields filled with the right roles change.
Here are the roles:
[image]

When i remove role 2 for example, the form looks like this:
[image]

role2 was being removed correctly, but role3 disappeared and the last two roles have the name of the last role (role8)

Why this happens? When i look to the formArray where all roles are saved, the array has the correct values, here is the evidence:

[image]

why the correct values are not shown in the view? Thank you for your help

EDIT: Here is the relevant typescript code:

```
this.sourcesForm = this.fb.group({
        sourceName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(255)]],
        sourceType: ['QUERY'],
        dsl: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(255)]],
        list: [''],
        roles: this.fb.array([this.buildRole()]),
        database: [''],
});

// save roles to temporary variable to map for the roles Formarray
let roles = [];
dslStatement.roles.forEach(role => {
    let oneRole = {
        roleName: role.name,
        identifier: true
    }
    if (role.role === 'IDENTIFIER')
        oneRole.identifier = true;
    else
        oneRole.identifier = false
    roles.push(oneRole);
});
// convert the variable to FormGroups, then the FormGroups to one FormArray 
// and at last set the FormArray to the roles of sourcesForm
const rolesFormGroups = roles.map(roles => this.fb.group(roles));
const rolesFormArray = this.fb.array(rolesFormGroups);
this.sourcesForm.setControl('roles', rolesFormArray);

buildRole(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        roleName: '',
        identifier: true
    });
}

addRole() {
    this.roles.push(this.buildRole());
}

removeRole(i: number) {
    this.roles.removeAt(i);
    console.log(this.roles.value);
    console.log(this.roles.controls);
}
```

Comment: can you make a working example ?

Comment: html is irrelevant here. Looks like some problems with data encapsulation. Show what you got

Comment: Show the code for `removeRole`

Comment: i updated the question by adding relevant code snippets

Comment: Try `(<FormArray>this.sourcesForm.get('roles')).removeAt(i)` in `removeRole` instead of `this.roles.removeAt(i)`

Comment: @karthikaruna i tried it. Unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: Can you put together a **simple** plunker or stackblitz that demonstrates the issue so we can take a look?

Comment: If I had to just throw out a guess ... I'd say that your `roles` data was getting out of sync with the `rolesFormArray`. It's not clear in the code shown above how you are updating the array as the data is changed. (The `removeRole` only seems to update the `role` data ... not the `rolesFormArray`.)

Comment: Hello @DeborahK. I used the same approach like you do in your reactive forms tutorial... why would the roles data in the sourcesForm get out of synch with the rolesFormArray? i let the value of the rolesFormArray and roles data show in the console, and they are exactly the same. however, when i manually press the "add more roles" button, the input fields are shown correctly (after a new formArray appears). but before i do that, when i click on the second last input field after deleting one ( the role name 6 field in the second picture), i get this error:

Comment: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with path: 'roles -> 6 -> roleName'

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Have you tried it with the current version?

Comment: i am using angular version 4.4.6. i think it is the current version

Comment: No. The current version is 5.x. And it seems to be fixed in Angular 5.

Comment: i updated my project to angular 5...and like you said, it works! so this issue was a bug in angular 4?

Comment: It appears so...

Comment: i never would think that this was an angular problem since i am developing with frameworks for barely one year. thank you very much for helping me. it is not the first time you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I built a stackblitz attempting to demonstrating the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dk-formarray

It uses **Angular 5.0** and does **NOT** have the problem.

I **was** able to reproduce this with the app from my course referenced above (**Angular 4**):

[image]

After deleting the "a" row, I get this:

[image]

Notice that the "a" is gone, but now I have two "c"s instead of "b" and "c".

Interestingly, if I save and then come back to the page, it displays correctly with "b" and "c".

So it appeared to be a bug that was fixed in Angular 5.

I was able to find a "work around" that worked for me in Angular 4.x:

```
deleteTag(index: number): void {
    this.tags.removeAt(index);
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.tags.value || []));
}
```

You may be able to do something similar to this (but I'm not sure your `roles` are set up just like my `tags`?)

But you are probably better off moving to Angular 5.

Comment: this is exactly the problem...sorry that i couldn't reproduce it on plnkr on my own. i tried to do it but got more errors.

Comment: unfortunately your workaround does not work for me. it shows the error `Cannot find control with path: 'roles -> 0 -> roleName'` but thats okay, i will move to angular 5 when my authorities in the company allow that.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
addRole() {
    this.roles = this.sourcesForm.get('roles') as FormArray;
    this.roles.push(this.buildRole());
}
```

**instead of**

```
  addRole() {
    this.roles.push(this.buildRole());
}
```